# MySQL INSERT ... SELECT. Using count(column) but not column works in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, having, sql-function, having-clause

When running:

```
SELECT '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 223
FROM timeslots
LEFT JOIN timeslotUsers ON timeslots.start = timeslotUsers.start
WHERE timeslots.start = '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
HAVING count(user_id) < timeslots.capacity
```

I am getting `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'timeslots.capacity' in 'having clause'`

I understand that `HAVING` acts on post-query values, and as such, adding capacity to the `SELECT` like this works:

```
SELECT '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 223, timeslots.capacity
```

The problem is, what I really want to do is:

```
INSERT INTO timslotUsers (start, user_id)
SELECT '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 223
FROM timeslots
LEFT JOIN timeslotUsers ON timeslots.start = timeslotUsers.start
WHERE timeslots.start = '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
HAVING count(user_id) < timeslots.capacity
```

and with that, as far as I know, the `select` parameters must match the `insert` parameters, so I cannot add in `capacity`. I'm unsure why `count(user_id)` works in `having` without `user_id` in the `select` parameters. `user_id` outside of `count()` also complains about `user_id` being 'unknown'. So I'm guessing `count()` somehow grabs the values. Is there a similar function which will simply grab the value of `capacity` so I can use it in `having`? Moving the `having` clause into the `where` complains about using `count()`.

Overall, what I'm trying to accomplish is a conditional insert into `timeslotUsers` that relies on a variable in the corresponding `timeslots` row being compared to the total count of `timeslotUsers` that match with `timeslots.start`. I'd like to do this without subqueries, if possible.

**Things I'd like to know:** Why does `count(user_id)` work in `HAVING` while `timeslots.capacity` or `timeslots.user_id` alone do not?  Is it itself running a subquery? Is there a function which allows me to use `capacity` like `count()` allows me to use `user_id`?

**Edit:**

sample data:

```
SELECT * FROM timeslotUsers;
+---------------------+---------+
| start               | user_id |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |     227 |
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |     228 |
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |     229 |
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00 |    2234 |
+---------------------+---------+
SELECT * FROM timeslots;
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
| start               | end                 | location  | capacity |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 2000-01-01 02:00:00 | someplace |        5 |
+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+----------+
```

When I run the insert above, I'd like another row to be placed in `timeslotUsers`, but only if there is less than `capacity` rows in `timeslotUsers` with matching `start`.

**Edit2:**

Wow. This works. (changed to `FROM timeslots` and added `GROUP BY capacity`)

```
INSERT INTO timeslotUsers (start, user_id)
SELECT timeslots.start, 223
FROM timeslots
LEFT JOIN timeslotUsers ON timeslots.start = timeslotUsers.start
WHERE timeslots.start = '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY capacity
HAVING COUNT(user_id) < capacity;
```

Is it even reasonable to ask why?

Comment: Is field user_id exists in two tables? Maybe adding prefix will help? I mean, having(table.user_id) not just having(user_id)

Comment: By adding an aggregate function like `COUNT()` in the `HAVING` clause, MySQL implicitly *groups* the resultset: that is, it is as though your query contains `GROUP BY NULL`.  It's actually not very clear what you're attempting to do—perhaps some sample data would help to exemplify the semantics of your intended query.

Comment: Interestingly enough, adding `GROUP BY timeslots.capacity` has everything working _except_ when there are zero entries in `timeslotUsers` with matching `start`.

Comment: By switching the `FROM` table and the `LEFT JOIN` table, I've gotten that edge case working. See edit2 above. I'd still like to know why COUNT(user_id) and capacity (after adding GROUP BY capacity) work inside HAVING, though.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the HAVING to a subselect on the WHERE clause should do it. This is untested but should be close:

```
INSERT INTO timeslotUsers (start, user_id) SELECT '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 223
FROM timeslots LEFT JOIN timeslotUsers ON timeslots.start = timeslotUsers.start 
WHERE timeslots.start = '2000-01-01 00:00:00' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) from 
timeslotUsers t where t.start = '2000-01-01 00:00:00') < timeslots.capacity
```

Here's a messier version that doesn't use the subquery

```
INSERT INTO timeslotUsers (start, user_id) SELECT '2000-01-01 00:00:00', 223
FROM timeslots LEFT JOIN timeslotUsers on timeslots.start = timeslotUsers.start 
WHERE timeslots.start = '2000-01-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY timeslots.start, 
timeslots.capacity HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN timeslotUsers.start IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 
1 END) < timeslots.capacity
```

This is abusing group by a little bit, but should also work.

Comment: I could do this with a subquery, but I feel like there is a way to do it without. This is a nice, workable method, however.

Comment: Actually the more I think about it the more I don't like the above answer either. It'd be "nicer" to check the condition before running the insert, and would look a little less like voodoo. Doing it this way seems too much like relying on a side effect.

Comment: Heh. My solution above (edit2) also ended up abusing `GROUP BY`. I'm starting to think sql wasn't really designed with these sorts of queries in mind.

Comment: My second solution also deals with the problem of having zero users in the timeslot, and it wont break when multiple timeslots have the same capacity (which i think yours will, as you are grouping only by capacity).

Comment: I think `WHERE timeslots.start = '...'` prevents any issue with same `capacity`s, as `start` is the primary key of `timeslots`, making the query pull only one `capacity` every time. Unless grouping works before `WHERE` narrows the rows looked at.

Comment: Ah. Yeah forgot about the where statement. How does yours go when capacity is set to 1?